# Data Corruption with MediumText and ASP/MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc

I have a website written in ASP with a mySQL database. ASP uses the ODBC 5.1 driver to connect to the database. Inside the database there is a varchar(8000) column (the length started small, but the application has evolved A LOT since its conception). Anyway, it recently became evident that the varchar column should be changed into a MEDIUMTEXT column. I made the change and everything appeared alright. However, whenever I do an UPDATE statement, the data in that column for that specific row gets corrupted. Do to the nature of the website, I am unable to provide data or example queries, but the queries are not using any functions or anything; just a straight UPDATE.

Everything works fine with the varchar, but blows up when I make the field a MEDIUMTEXT. The corruption I'm talking about is as follows:

ٔڹ����￺�����￺������￺ߘ����￺ߘ����￺����

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you getting that output?  via code, or query analyzer/enterprise manager?

Comment: ASP and phpMyAdmin both show that gibberish. I'm not using an analyzer or enterprise manager....

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked encodings (ASP+HTML+DB)? Using UTF8?

Not using UTF8 and that text is not English , right?

Comment: I did check and I am not using UTF8

Answer (score 0):

You might have a version specific bug. I searched for "mysql alter table mediumtext corruption" and there were some bugs specifically having to do with code pages and non-latin1 character sets.

Your best best is conduct a survey of the table, comparing it against a backup. If this is a MyISAM table, you might want to recreate the table with [CHECKSUM option enabled](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html). What does a CHECK TABLE tell you? If an ALTER TABLE isn't working for you, you could consider partitioning the mediumtext field into it's own table, or duplicating the table contents using a variation of an INSERT...SELECT:

```
CREATE TABLE b LIKE a;
ALTER TABLE b MODIFIY b.something MEDIUMTEXT;
INSERT INTO b SELECT * FROM a LIMIT x,1000;
-- now check those 1000 rows --
```

By inserting a few rows at a time and then checking them, it you might be able to tease out what kind of input isn't converting well.

Check dmesg and syslog output to see if you've got ram or disk issues. I have seen table corruptions occur due to ECC errors, bad raid controllers, bad sectors and faulty network transmission. You might attempt the ALTER TABLE on a comparable machine and see if it checks out.